# The characteristic of a ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Suppose $n\cdot 1\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Here $n\cdot 1$ means the sum of $n$ unities. I would like to prove that $R$ has characteristic $0$. To this end, I want to show that we cannot have $n\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in R$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Assume for contradiction that $n\cdot a=0$. Oberve that
$$n\cdot a=a\cdot(n\cdot 1).$$
Could you please tell how to do next in order to reach a contradiction? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $n·1 ≠ 0$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$, then certainly the statement “$n·a = 0$ *for all* $a ∈ R$ for some $n ∈ ℕ$” is contradicted by testing it for $a = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For contradiction you have to start with: let there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in R$. Now put $a=1$ to get the contradiction.